# How can I change a System.Array into a System.Object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a variable stored as a System.Array displayed as;

```
Site        : https://value.sharepoint.com/
Email       : value@value.co.uk
DisplayName : value
UniqueId    : value
AcceptedAs  : value@value.co.uk
WhenCreated : 24/01/2019 06:02:45
InvitedBy   : value_value.co.uk#ext#@value.onmicrosoft.com
```

When I try to export this variable as a file it shows in the same format. As this is not in the correct structure for a table (shown below) I am unable to use this data when I try to use it in Power BI.

```
Site                                               Email                ect                                                                                                                  
----                                               ----                 ----                                                                                                                 
https://value.sharepoint.com/                      value@value.co.uk    ect
```

I need to get my data into the structure shown above. I have tried;

```
$Test = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property  $ExternalUsers
```

However this results in the following error;

```
New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' required by parameter 'Property'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I then tried to loop through all of the items in the array and then create an object for each item, before adding it to a "Master Object";

```
foreach($var in $ExternalUsers){
    $Test = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property  $ExternalUsers
    $Test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Site -Value $var.Site
    $Test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Email -Value $var.Email
    $TestObject += $Test
}
```

This got each item into the correct structure but when I tried to add all the items back into the one variable I got the error;

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
```

Any ideas how I could get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you have an array (`System.Object[]`) containing PSObjects with the properties `Site`, `Email` etc. 
A structure like that is ideal for exporting to CSV file, which you can then import in a spreadsheed application like Excel for instance.

For that you use the cmdlet `Export-Csv` like this:

```
$ExternalUsers | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE OUTPUT CSV FILE' -NoTypeInformation
```

If the output you show is complete, it seems there is only one element in the array. You can check this by looking at `$ExternalUsers.Count`.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *"As this is not in the correct structure for a table"*, because you can quite easily display it as table using

```
$ExternalUsers | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Output on console window:

```
Site                          Email             DisplayName UniqueId AcceptedAs        WhenCreated         InvitedBy                                   
----                          -----             ----------- -------- ----------        -----------         ---------                                   
https://value.sharepoint.com/ value@value.co.uk value       value    value@value.co.uk 24/01/2019 06:02:45 value_value.co.uk#ext#@value.onmicrosoft.com
```

If what you want is less properties, just loop through the array and select the properties you want to keep from the objects in it:

```
$Shortened = $ExternalUsers | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object Site, Email
}

$Shortened | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Will produce:

```
Site                          Email            
----                          -----            
https://value.sharepoint.com/ value@value.co.uk
```

I'm not into Power BI, but remember that the `Format-Table` cmdlet is for display purposes on console ONLY.
It does NOT provide anything else but a **view** on the data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Theo, Export-Csv worked for me. I tried this previously but instead I was using the -InputObject parameter which was populating the csv with counts of the data instead of the data.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$TestObject = @()
```

and no need to specify (-Property  $ExternalUsers)

```
$Test = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
```